# How to split string using Substring

Tags: c#, substring

I have a string like '/Test1/Test2', and i need to take Test2 separated from the same. How can i do that in c# ?

Comment: look at the string.Split() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string toSplit= "/Test1/Test2";

toSplit.Split('/');
```

or

```
toSplit.Split(new [] {'/'}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

to split, the latter will remove the empty string.

Adding `.Last()` will get you the last item.

e.g.

```
toSplit.Split('/').Last();
```

Comment: SplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries :P or something like that I forget the exact name, to get rid of the empty you would get because of the first /

Answer (score 2):

Using .Split and a little bit of LINQ, you could do the following

```
string str = "/Test1/Test2";
string desiredValue = str.Split('/').Last();
```

Otherwise you could do

```
string str = "/Test1/Test2";
string desiredValue = str;
if(str.Contains("/"))
   desiredValue = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Thanks Binary Worrier, forgot that you'd want to drop the '/', darn fenceposts

Comment: Possibly `string desiredValue = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("/")+1);` because you don't want the seperator?

Answer (score 2):

Use [.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
string foo = "/Test1/Test2";
string extractedString = foo.Split('/').Last(); // Result Test2
```

This site have quite a few [examples of splitting strings in C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split). It's worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

string[] arr = string1.split('/');
string result = arr[arr.length - 1];

Answer (score 1):

```
string [] split = words.Split('/');
```

This will give you an array `split` that will contain "", "Test1" and "Test2".

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the Test2 portion, try this:

```
string fullTest = "/Test1/Test2";
string test2 = test.Split('/').ElementAt(1);  //This will grab the second element.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string inputString = "/Test1/Test2";
            string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "/Test1/"};
            string[] result;
            result = inputString.Split(stringSeparators,
                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                foreach (string s in result)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}",s);

                }


OUTPUT : Test2
```