# substring not working correctly

Tags: c#, substring

im trying to make c# read text from each line in a txt file then set a variable based on the line this is the code im trying to use

```
string line;
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("update.txt");
StreamReader stRead = file.OpenText();
while ((line = stRead.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("version=") == true)
    {
        Version.TryParse(line.Substring(8), out version);
    }
    if (line.StartsWith("md5=") == true)
    {
        md5 = line.Substring(4);
    }
    if (line.StartsWith("url=") == true)
    {
        url = line.Substring(4);
    }
    if (line.StartsWith("changelog=") == true)
    {
        changelog = line.Substring(10);
    }
}
stRead.Close();
```

i put breakpoints in to see what was happening and its reading the txt file but not setting the variables for some reason i declared these variables above the code

```
private Version version;
private string md5;
private string url;
private string changelog;
```

only the version variable gets set please help thanks

oh and this is the test txt im using

```
version=1.1.0.0
md5=564C8AACFBDAA1F5A0AA44A85C53BF55
url=fbnfhbcfn
changelog=bug fixes
```

Comment: You need to show sample input file (small, but showing all inputs you expect, make sure to not type it in here, but copy/paste to avoid fixing bad input like wrong case...).

Comment: this is the test txt version=1.1.0.0
md5=564C8AACFBDAA1F5A0AA44A85C53BF55
url=fbnfhbcfn
changelog=bug fixes

Comment: Why don't you split by `=`?

Comment: @Prix how would i do that

Comment: [Using the split function on `line`?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx)

Comment: never used split before so will look into it

Comment: This is pretty much what you want to do on each line you're reading [How to split string using Substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570289/how-to-split-string-using-substring)

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code, but split would make it a big more generic.

Comment: Be more specific about what you see and what is not working. Saying "not setting the variables for some reason" doesn't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: thanks guys managed to get it to work using split now to just make changelog able to list multiple strings and im set thanks again

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your *code* - which can be verified by inlining reader: `var stRead = 
   new StringReader("version=1.1.0.0\nmd5=564C8AACFBDAA1F5A0AA44A85C53BF55\nurl=fbnfhbcfn\nchangelog=bug fixes");`. Most likely Candide's suggestion about reading file from wrong location is the reason.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the file was in the directory as it downloads it from a online server before doing this code and i set up breakpoints to see if it was reading it which it was it just wasnt setting the strings but i fixed it now thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

The code is fine the way it is. Some things to keep in mind:

1. The text file `update.txt` needs to be in the same directory as the executable. So, if a console application or a windows application it should be in `bin/Debug`, when you start debugging for instance. If you have included it in your project, ensure that the build action is set to "Content", and "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Always". (This is found under the properties of the file in the solution).
2. The file `update.txt` needs to be readable by the executable/runtime